# Calculating the variance from a confidence interval or sample size

Tags: variance, estimation, auc

I read a paper reporting an AUC (area under the curve) of 0.72 with a 95% confidence interval from 0.68 to 0.74.
How can I calculate the variance of this AUC (I don't have the original data set, just the AUC and confidence interval)?
In another paper I only have a reported AUC (=0.65) but no confidence interval, although I do know that $N=733$. Is there a way to estimate the variance here?

Note that the AUC is a statistic which lies between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you know how the CI was computed?

Comment: Although you may know this under random guessing the AUC theoretically would be 0.50.

Comment: @whuber No this is not mentioned; I also have no other data besides N (so no sensitivity etc..)

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways of calculating error bars for AUC values. The first method, sometimes called [DeLong's method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531595?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), uses the fact that the AUC value is a rescaled [Mann-Whitney U statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Area-under-curve_.28AUC.29_statistic_for_ROC_curves). The U statistic is asymptotically normally distributed, so the usual confidence interval approaches can be applied. See the Wikipedia page for details. If you know the sample size, you can apply this in reverse to get the variance of the AUC.

The second most popular method for AUC error bars is simple bootstrapping. There is not much you can do to reverse the bootstrap to get a variance estimate unfortunately.